# Numerical integration of given points, simple/easy way

Tags: numerical-analysis, numerics, integration, integral-equations

I have the `x` and the `f(x)` for a set of `x`. I don't know the function, actually. This is sufficient to integrate it?

The `x` value might span from `1` to no more than `50`, usually around `10`. While `y` is always negative and it's peak might pass `-100`.

What's the simplest approach?

```
x 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 9
y 0 -3 -5 -7 -5 -3 -2 -1 -1 0
```

May I ask the Python code com compute that?

Comment: Cross-post with [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070162/numerical-integration-of-given-points-simple-easy-way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scipy.integrate` with a given method (Simpson's rule or composite trapezoidal rule for instance):

```
from scipy import integrate
x = array1
y = array2
int = integrate.cumtrapz(y, x, initial = 0)
```

See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html#scipy.integrate.cumtrapz) for more.

Comment: Got this as result, `[  0.   -1.5  -5.5 -11.5 -17.5 -21.5 -24.  -25.5 -26.5 -27. ]`. But a I was expecting just one number.

Comment: @KcFnMi You can take the absolute value of the last element of the array.

Comment: The others are there just to complicate?

Comment: @KcFnMi You have all the intermediate values since it's a cumulative function. Try, to be sure, to integrate between 0 and 1 the points generated by a simple function like $x^2$.

Comment: Ok, got the idea. Are there any special requirements I should pay attention?

Comment: @KcFnMi Not that I am aware of!